# Configure asp.net Web Controls in external configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've an asp.net web application accessed by different users with different roles.

Now I've to enable/disable and show/hide controls (label, textbox, buttons in grid, third party controls) based on a logic involves context variables and users role.

I want to avoid to write IF statements in `onLoad` method.

I tried to create an xml file like this:

```
<root>
   <page name="page1" mode="insert">
       <control id="txtName" property="Visible" value="True" />
```

then in a `basePage` class I tried to cycle all `Page.Controls` to set property with propertyInfo.

Problems starts when I have ascx inside ascx or gridview with command buttons to disable.

It is possible to configure those control's behaviors in an external configuration file?

Is there a framework allowing this?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework controls do not do this inherently.  Though, the best way to do this is by creating a control library, override the controls you typically use, and then have each of those controls do a lookup to the XML file, and import the settings.

It's MUCH cheaper for the control to go to the repository, rather than the page to iterate through the controls and then do the work.

HTH.